# Cross-platform compiling using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, cross-platform, cmake, scons

Given:

- C++ code base with more than 500K LOC
- The same base code used for Windows (Visual Studio 9 2008) and Linux (RHEL)

Most of the frequent task during development is of course edit/compile/fix (therefore we like programming :)). Most of our developers are with Visual Studio background only and IMHO it's pretty powerful.

Is there any way to compile on Linux machine remotely from within VS?

I found [this site](http://playstation2-linux.com/docs/howto/display_doc.php?docid=74) and [this other site](http://www.atrevido.net/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=3f409151-db81-4932-8502-c7592f645b4c) but Visual Studio 9 2008 doesn't support nmake, while I need to add command line for at least build/rebuild and clean. I found that I can add one command as a pre-build event or as external tool (*Menu->Tools->...*). But it is only 1 command, while I need 3 commands.

Maybe is there some other way?

Thanks
Dima

Answer (score 2):

If you can "only add one command", then of the solution should be wrapping the sequence of commands that you want to run into a .bat file. I haven't tried doing this from Visual Studio, but I would be really surprised if it didn't work.

[Here](http://www.soulcast.com/post/show/47434/Gnu-cross-compiling-for-Linux-on-Windows) is an article about cross-compiling Linux code, using gcc, for Linux in a Windows-hosted environment.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put the three commands in a bat file and invoked the batch file as a one pre-build event command?, does this fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the three commands separated by semicolons.

```
command1;command2;command3
```

I have not tested this, and won't be able to until I reboot, but I think this might work.